# Unable install Strapi plugin [strapi-plugin-import-content]

Tags: plugins, strapi

I trying to acquire this plugins which available with its GitHub directory
https://github.com/jbeuckm/strapi-plugin-import-content

However, the last command:(not workable)

```
npm run setup --plugins
```

It prompt me this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAWbJ.jpg)

May I know how could i solve it?

I try "npm cache clean --force" but it still not workable

Answer (score 0):

'npm run setup' was available in Strapi 3.x but as far as I know it is no longer available latest by version 4.x - I guess you are using Strapi 4.x.
https://github.com/jbeuckm/strapi-plugin-import-content was updated 4 years ago so I think it was designed for Strapi 3.x.